# space before a large character?

Tags: c++, string

space before a large character? How to create function?

```
std::string str = Foo("HelloWorld");
std::cout<<str;

// it needs to output this
Hello World
```

Comment: Hint: Look at `std::find_if()`, `std::isupper()`, and `std::string::insert()`

Comment: Heh... might I suggest... <drumroll please> a REGEX? (Booo!)

Answer (score 0):

This will work. Note that it will insert a space before the first word if it's capitalized

```
string foo(const string& str) {
    string out;
    for (const auto& c : str) {
        if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
            out += " ";
            out += c;
        } else {
            out += c;
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: *This will work.* -- It won't work on systems that do not use ASCII or systems that use other upper case characters that do not fall between `A` and `Z`.  Instead, use `std::isupper` instead of checking if the character is between `A` and `Z`.